# Passing instantion of an object as an argument when handling new pthread

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I can create a `pthread` and pass an ID of this thread as an argument of the function that handles this new thread by this construction:

```
 pthread_t thread;
 pthread_create(&thread, NULL,
         someFunction, (void *) fd);
 // And now handle it with this
 void * someFunction(void *threadid) { }
```

But is there also any possibility, how to pass there an instantion of some object instead of that threadid?
E.g.:

```
MyObject * o = new MyObject();
pthread_t thread;
       /*and now how to pass o as an paramether, 
        *to be able to work with it later in 
        *my void * someFunction(void *threadid) { } ? 
        */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a composite object:

```
class MyWrapper
{
    public: void* threadId;
    public: MyObject* o;

    public: MyWrapper(void* threadId, MyObject* o)
    {
        this->threadId = threadId;
        this->o = o;
    }
};
...
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, someFunction, new MyWrapper(threadid, o));
```

And the function:

```
void * someFunction(void *state)
{
     MyWrapper* wrapper = (MyWrapper*)state;
     ...
}
```

Comment: but how then shall the declaration of someFunction look like?

Comment: The same, you just change the way you retrieve the thread state, I've updated my answer.